# How to replace I18nVariableLanguageRealm controller?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have done custom module with .class.inc and .module file. Class file is added in module info file.

Inside class file:

```
/**
 * Controller for Language realms.
 */
class MyModuleI18nVariableLanguageRealm extends I18nVariableLanguageRealm {
  public function getKey() {
    return isset($this->current_key) ? $this->current_key : FALSE;
  }
}
```

Inside module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_variable_realm_info
 */
function mymodule_i18n_variable_variable_realm_info() {
  $realm['language'] = array(
    'title' => t('Language'),
    'weight' => 1,
    'controller class' => 'MyModuleI18nVariableLanguageRealm',
    'store class' => 'VariableStoreRealmStore',
    // Variables for this realm can be selected from a list.
    'select' => TRUE,
    'select path' => 'admin/config/regional/i18n/variable',
    // Name for variables that belong to this realm: 'multilingual' variable/s
    'variable name' => t('multilingual'),
    'variable class' => 'i18n-variable',
    // Automatically handle these variables in system settings forms.
    'form settings' => TRUE,
    'form switcher' => TRUE,
  );
  return $realm;
}
```

but debugging shows that custom controller isn't in use. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You created a child class all right, but I don't see any part of code that would tell Drupal to actually go and use your class. If you think it should be autoloaded, could you share a link to docs that gave this impression? (and I call it "impression" because apparently it isn't autoloaded). Anyway +1 from me, would like to see it answered, too. Curiosity if nothing else.

Comment: @Mołot thanks, I thought   'controller class' => 'MyModuleI18nVariableLanguageRealm' would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

In the Drupal world 'replace' in your context is usually synonymous with 'alter'.

Try this:

```
function mymodule_i18n_variable_variable_realm_info_alter(&$realm) {
  $realm['language']['controller class'] = 'MyModuleI18nVariableLanguageRealm';
}
```

Comment: in variable_realm.api.php there is no such hook, only hook_variable_realm_info. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: It was [added 19 months ago](http://drupalcode.org/project/variable.git/log/refs/heads/7.x-1.x) apparently. I've never even heard of that module before to be honest, but any module that allows you to change something defined in a hook should be doing it by way of `drupal_alter()`. If they're not, it's probably worth a feature request to the module

Comment: this maybe be the reason, because on cc this hook is not invoked. I thought weight argument do the job, for now it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm according to the code it should do: `$realm_info = module_invoke_all('variable_realm_info'); drupal_alter('variable_realm_info', $realm_info);`, line 80 [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/variable.git/blob/eb7715883a11b4cf73c618f4582d6d1ec9cefb54:/variable_realm/variable_realm.module)